# How to get X to ignore my primary GPU?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg, amd-radeon

I have a MSI B450 Tomahawk Max motherboard with two GPUs in it.  My "main" GPU is an NVidia GeForce GTX 1660, and is located in the primary GPU slot (PCI_E1, located closest to the CPU and running at 16x speed).  My second GPU is a cheap little AMD Radeon HD 5450, located in PCI_E4, which is the only other slot that can accommodate a full size card. My Ryzen 5 has no integrated graphics capability.

I would like to have my X windows system use -only- the Radeon Card so that my NVidia can be freed up for other things, like GPU passthrough to a VM and such. I have followed [this guide](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/) while using [this as a reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF).  I managed to get everything setup so that my nvidia card is grabbed by the vfio-pci stubs at boot and the proper drivers are blacklisted initially, but are able to be loaded later.  All seems well, EXCEPT...I can't start X with the nVidia card stubbed out.  I just end up with a blank, black screen on my console.  I can ssh into the box, but the console is blank.

Ironically, if I switch things around to make the Radeon card stubbed out, then X starts just fine.  I can also run both cards at the same time, with each driving a different monitor.  But I can't get X to start using only the Radeon card.

I  did try [this solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#X_does_not_start_after_enabling_vfio_pci) given on my reference page, but it did not work - I ended up with precisely the same situation.  It seemed to have no effect at all.

I posted my Xorg.0.log files for the two situations below.  The Radeon-stub one works.  The Nvidia-stub one doesn't work - it ends with complaining that no screens are configured.  I tried to wade through it to find a clue, but the configuration of X is very opaque to me, given all of the auto-configuration going on behind the scenes.  I can't figure out why anything works or fails.

It would be nice if I knew how to view my current X config, so at least I know what "good" looks like.

How do I force X to use only my Radeon GPU?

My kernel parameters are as follows for my two stubbed configurations:

Nvidia Stub:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic root=UUID=09d61674-efb6-441a-b9ab-f958990e5c31 ro debug splash dis_ucode_ldr vfio-pci.ids=10de:2184,10de:1aeb,10de:1aec,10de:1aed module_blacklist=nvidia,snd_hda_intel,i2c_nvidia_gpu vt.handoff=7
```

Radeon Stub:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic root=UUID=09d61674-efb6-441a-b9ab-f958990e5c31 ro debug splash module_blacklist=radeon,snd_hda_intel vt.handoff=7
```

[Radeon Stub Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/fRV2kW4pjR/)  (Works, using on Nvidia GPU)

[Nvidia Stub Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VN8zwkT8Dz/)  (Fails, saying "Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section)

[Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9wHTzzxFtZ/) with no stubs, one monitor on Nvidia card, one on Radeon Card (works fine)

EDIT:  Per @dirkt's suggestion, I tried adding the "nouveau" driver to the kernel command line blacklist.  The Xorg.0 log file is linked below.  It had no effect at all.

[Nvidia Stub + blacklisted nouveau Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nvqkTfSgyY/)

Also, note that at this point I'm not doing anything with my VM yet.  I'm just trying to get X to run without using the Nvidia card.

I also tried removing the nvidia card from my system.  X works, but of course I can't pass through a non-existent video card to a VM them.  The differences I noted between this log file and the Nvidia-stub file are that there no mentions of a nvidia/nouveau drivers.  Comparing these log files also highlighted that the first error in [nvidia-stub](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VN8zwkT8Dz/) is the following (my nvidia GPU is on PCI bus address 26).  This is almost certainly because the nvidia card is stubbed out, but that's precisely why I want X to **ignore** it.

```
(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:26:00.0: -19
```

Here is that log file:

[Nvidia Card removed Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/f22vky2Jvq/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a lot of digging I found that the answer lies [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xorg.conf/#lbAL), in the descriptions of the options available for xorg's "OutputClass" section:

> Option "PrimaryGPU" "boolean"
>
> This option specifies that the matched device should be treated as the
> primary GPU, replacing the selection of the GPU used as output by
> the firmware. If multiple output devices match an OutputClass section
> with the PrimaryGPU option set, the first one enumerated becomes the
> primary GPU.

Adding this to the relevant file in the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d told X to not use the radeon card as my primary GPU.  In my case, my file was called "10-radeon.conf".  This told X to ignore the GPU that was designated as "Primary" by the boot sequence, and instead use the card matched by the given OutputClass.

```
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "Radeon"
        MatchDriver "radeon"
        Driver "radeon"
        Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection
```

Note that this is the ONLY system modification needed to make X ignore the primary GPU (in my case).  No special kernel parameters or other mods were needed.  All this does is ignore the nvidia GPU for the X configuration.  It does not stub-out the GPU with vfio-pci stubs or anything else - but it does prep the card for that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

First, make debugging easier by temporarily disabling the VM. Once you successfully ignore the NVidia card on the host system, enable it again.

Your log says you are using the `nouveau` driver, so blacklist the nouveau kernel module on the host system, see e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841876/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver) (or google "blacklist nouveau kernel module" for your distro).

Use `dmesg` after boot to see if the blacklisting worked; compare the output before and after the blacklisting change.

Once that works, your X log should show it only coming up with the Radeon. If this does not work, try a custom `xorg.conf` (yes, these are still a thing, even though some people deny this).

Then get the hardware passthrough to the VM working, and then make sure you use the right driver on the VM guest OS (possibly you want the closed source `nvidia` driver, depending on what you want to do with it).

Comment: Thanks, dirkt.  I tried your suggestion, see my edits to my OP.  no luck yet.

Comment: See edit: use `dmesg` to check if the blacklisting worked. From your X log, it didn't.

Comment: can you point to where the X log file indicates that it is using the nouveau driver?  lspci lists several kernel modules associated with that card, and states that the "kernel driver in use" is the nvidia one, not the nouveau.  Also, dmesg never mentions nouveau anywhere except in the kernel cmdline when I blacklist it here.  The non-blacklisted dmesg doesn't mention nouveau at all.

Comment: hunh, interestingly, lspci shows -all- of my blacklisted drivers, whether I blacklist them or not...  ```Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia```.  However, in the blacklisted case, the "Kernel driver in use" reads "vfio-pci", or "nvidia" when not blacklisted.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong link - the log file at the bottom indeed shows only Radeon. It's quite possible that now the `nvidia` kernel module gets loaded, even though the X driver doesn't. Please check with `dmesg`, not with `lspci`. If both the `nvidia` and the `nouveau` module use the card, then either is something very wrong, or something very interesting happens on your machine - normally those are mutually exclusive. `vfio-pci` is the passthrough, which means you did *not* disable the VM ...

Comment: how do I check with dmesg?  like I said, I see no mention of nouveau anywhere in the dmesg, except in the kernel parameters line.  vfio-pci grabs the card at system boot, NOT when the VM is started.  So the VM is not started just because you see vfio-pci as the card driver.

Comment: the relevant lines in the lspci output looks like this: "        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia"  I don't believe this means that all of the "kernel modules" are in use - only nvidia is listed as in use.  I'm guessing the kernel modules line just indicates what modules -could- be used.

Comment: yes, that's correct RE lspci.  See "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47208/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-drivers-and-kernel-modules"

Comment: So the `nvidia` kernel module **in the VM** uses the card? Or in the `nvidia` kernel module in the host? If the latter, also blacklist the `nvidia` kernel module in the host. (And to avoid this complication I have suggested not starting the VM, so you know that anything you see can only happen in the host).

Comment: dirkt, the VM does not exist yet.  I am in the prep stages to create a VM which WILL use the nvidia GPU.  When I boot the system with no special kernel parameters, the HOST kernel uses the nvidia driver on the card.  When I boot the kernel with "nvidia stub" parameters, the host uses "vfio-stub" on the nvidia card, radeon on my radeon card, and I get a blank screen.  I never even get to the stage where I could start the VM.

All of the discussion thus far has been about the HOST system ONLY.  sorry for the any confusion.